How to solve com.google.android.recaptcha:recaptcha:18.1.2 in Flutter

SDK issues in your latest production release
com.google.android.recaptcha:recaptcha:18.1.2
com.google.android.recaptcha:recaptcha has added this note for SDK
version 18.1.2:
A critical security vulnerability was discovered in reCAPTCHA
Enterprise for Mobile. The vulnerability has been patched in the
latest SDK release. Customers will need to update their Android
application with the reCAPTCHA Enterprise for Mobile SDK, version
18.4.0 or above. We strongly recommend you update to the latest version as soon as possible.

i am working in flutter. Flutter version 3.13.9 using it
how to slove that issues
i did try latest version of auth using it in flutter. i am not using reCAPTCHA.

you just need to update the version to 18.4.0 or above.

tell me which version are upadte

I slove the problem
android/app/build gradle
dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.android.recaptcha:recaptcha:18.4.0'
}
configurations.all {
exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-safetynet'
}

**android/app/build gradle**
dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.android.recaptcha:recaptcha:18.4.0'
}
if You have problem also play-services-safetynet then u added 

//com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet has added this note //for SDK version 18.0.0:
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-safetynet'
}

